# i am trying to play one mp3 file after another (one as intro) but it won't work. How can i do this?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to use a intro sound for the mp3 files. After playing the intro the original track should start to play. i mean the original mp3 plays right after the intro ends. Here i have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id='top' onended="playOrg();" preload='none' src='http://www.sounddogs.com/previews/59/mp3/607322_SOUNDDOGS__th.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'> </audio>
<a href='#' class='btn' id='audioControl'> START </a>
```

And here the javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var yourAudio = document.getElementById('top');
var ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'STOP';
    $('.btn').html('START');
    $('audio').trigger('pause');
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'START' : 'STOP';
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio [method]();
    return false; };

function playOrg(){                   
  yourAudio.setAttribute('onended','orgPlayed()');
  yourAudio.src='http://www.sounddogs.com/sound-effects/59/mp3/606540_SOUNDDOGS__sf.mp3';
  yourAudio.play();
  console.log('playOrg()');
}

function orgPlayed(){                   
  yourAudio.setAttribute('onended','playOrg()');
  yourAudio.src='http://www.sounddogs.com/previews/59/mp3/607322_SOUNDDOGS__th.mp3';
  yourAudio.pause();
  yourAudio.currentTime = 0;
  console.log('orgPlayed()');
}

</script>
```

When i press start the file plays and on the end it calls the playOrg() function witch should change some attributes and should play the original track. Then the second file should play and on its end this time the orgPlayed() function should be called and set back the attributes so that it is ready for the other play.

So i want to use intro track for all my track on the site. But i can't accomplish that. i  appreciate any upcoming help.

PS: Actually there is a loop for all tracks in my original code but i summarised it here. Please don't ask why i couldn't find better mp3 test files :).

Comment: Try `yourAudio.setAttribute('onended',orgPlayed);`

Comment: Your second function seems to pause the audio, but never starts() it again. By any chance is it stuck in pause state due to this? (sorry, im a hands on debugger, im crap at evaluating code by reading it, so i may be wrong)

Comment: i tried but no luck @putvande. here is a fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/skeletor/hhf5z/

Comment: yes @lee that is planed to do so. the second function sets it back and makes it ready for the next play when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the my problem. Instead of reloading the new track with "currentTime=0" i tried to reload with "load()" , and now it works. I guess sometime we need to sleep over such problems :). Thanks to everyone ;).

```
<audio id='top' onended="playOrg();" preload='none' src='top10/intro/1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'> </audio>
<a href='#' class='btn' id='audioControl'>START</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var yourAudio = document.getElementById('top');
var ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {
  if (ctrl.innerHTML=='START') {
    ctrl.innerHTML='STOP';
    yourAudio.play();
  }else if (ctrl.innerHTML=='STOP'){
    ctrl.innerHTML='START';
    yourAudio.pause();
  }    
}

function playOrg(){
  var myPlayer= document.getElementById('top');
  myPlayer.setAttribute('onended','orgPlayed()');
  myPlayer.src='top10/tarkan.mp3';
  myPlayer.pause();
  myPlayer.load();
  myPlayer.play();
}

function orgPlayed(){
  var myPlayer= document.getElementById('top');
  myPlayer.setAttribute('onended','playOrg()');
  myPlayer.src='top10/intro/1.mp3';
  myPlayer.pause();
  myPlayer.load();
  ctrl.innerHTML='START';
}

</script>
```

now i realised another way to solve this. i could use two audio tags with one intro source and the other the original source. and then after the first one ends i could play the second using either a function or directly onended="document.getElementById('top2').play();"

i mean something like this:

```
<audio id='top1' onended="play second(with a function or directly)" preload='none' src='intro' type='audio/mpeg'> </audio>
<audio id='top2' onended="make ready for another play (with a function or directly)" preload='none' src='original' type='audio/mpeg'> </audio>
<a href='#' class='btn' id='audioControl'>START</a>
```

Comment: actually instead of redefining the "top" element i could continue with the  "yourAudio" that was initialised at the beginning.